# Place Switch/check box along with tittle of the Ant Design table reatc js

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am new to react js. So I need your's help. I want a switch/checkbox with the title of the table. In this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-curie-lyovv?file=/index.js, the bottom switch must be with the title of the table. How can I move this?

Example: | `Name <switch />` | `Age <switch />` | `Address <switch />` |

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your columns titles follow this structure:

`title: <p>COLUMN_TITLE <Switch defaultChecked onChange={onChange} /></p>`

See below.

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: <p>Name <Switch defaultChecked onChange={onChange} /></p>,
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name",
    render: (text, record) => (
      <div>
        <Input
          disabled={val}
          component="input"
          className="ant-input"
          type="text"
        />
      </div>
    )
  },
  {
    title: <p>Age <Switch defaultChecked onChange={onChange} /></p>,
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age",
    render: (text, record) => (
      <div>
        <Input component="input" className="ant-input" type="text" />
       </div>
    )
  },
  {
    title: <p>Address <Switch defaultChecked onChange={onChange} /></p>,
    dataIndex: "address",
    key: "address",
    render: (text, record) => (
      <div>
        <Input component="input" className="ant-input" type="text" />
      </div>
    )
  }
];
```

This way your `Switch` is included in the header of the table next to the column title. Previously you were including it in the render of the column. See the updated sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-cache-9jin9).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need another help from you. Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62255567/move-expandicon-icon-to-right-and-remove-empty-space-from-expanded-table-ant-des) and help me out.

Comment: @Rich Just answered the question.