# Move expandIcon icon to right and remove empty space from expanded table Ant Design and React.js

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need your help to solve this problem.

I am using the Ant Design table and I am stuck here. I want the expand row icon should be at the right(Next to delete in the given sandbox code) of table current it is on left and when we expand a row the expanded contents leave a small space in left, I want to remove it. i.e. it should not have any extra space in left. Please help me out, guys.

Sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-mountain-ft8m1?file=/index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potential solution could be to make use of `expandIconColumnIndex`, a prop that can be passed to an expandable antd `Table` component as well as adding an extra row for the expander. By doing this, you can set the `expandIconColumnIndex` to the index of the last (empty) row (in your case the index is 4), this way the icon will appear to the right of the `Delete` action. This will avoid creating space on the left and will move the icon to the right most column. This is the method that requires the least refactor given your code. Below is your updated columns.

```
const columns = [
  { title: "Name", dataIndex: "name", key: "name" },
  { title: "Age", dataIndex: "age", key: "age" },
  { title: "Address", dataIndex: "address", key: "address" },
  {
    title: "Action",
    dataIndex: "",
    key: "x",
    render: (r) => <div>
    <a>Delete</a> 
    <a onClick={()=>expandRows(r.key)}>  ex</a>
    </div>
  },
   { title: "", dataIndex: "", key: "expand", width: 1},
];
```

And here is the updated `Table`.

```
<Table
   expandIconColumnIndex={4}
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    expandIcon={({ expanded, onExpand, record }) =>
      expanded ? (
        <UpOutlined style={{float: 'right'}} onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
      ) : (
        <DownOutlined onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
      )
    }
    expandable={{
      expandedRowRender: record => <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{renderTable()}</p>
    }}
  />
```

In order to remove the left space from the nested table, you will need to overwrite Ant Design's CSS, which includes more padding for the nested table to act as indentation and differentiate it from the rest of the table. I recommend you keep it the way it is but if you really don't want to have that space you can overwrite their style by adding the className `parentTable` to your first table, and then `nestedTable` for the nested table (found in `renderTable`). Then add the following CSS to your style sheet.

```
.parentTable
  table
  tbody
  .ant-table-expanded-row.ant-table-expanded-row-level-1
  > td {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.nestedTable > div > div > div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Here is the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-dawn-97qp9?file=/index.js).

Comment: Thanks, Matt Croak, but still the expanded row has empty space left to them. `style={{ margin: 0 }}` didn't work I guess.

Comment: @Rich in order to do that you will need to overwrite ant design's css. They intentionally add padding to the nested tables to differentiate them from the parent table. I recommend you leave it as it is but if you really want to remove the extra space I provided CSS changes that will overwrite ant design and give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: You are right and thanks for the solution. You saved my one day.

Comment: Again I need your help. Please look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301807/make-a-card-component-as-drawer-ant-design) once. Thank you.

Comment: @Rich please accept this current answer. I will happy to help with the next one if you accept this one.

Comment: I am new to this. So I delayed accepting. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Rich No worries. I'll look at the other Q you posted.

Comment: Thank you. That was solved. So don't look that link.

Comment: If possible please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326450/set-value-to-state-react-js) once. I am struggling from past few hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming to this in the future, the correct way to do this is to use the antd table props.

The expandIcon prop of the antd table takes a function that returns a react node.

```
customExpandIcon(props) {
    if (props.expanded) {
        return <a style={{ color: 'black' }} onClick={e => {
            props.onExpand(props.record, e);
        }}><Icon type="minus" /></a>
    } else {
        return <a style={{ color: 'black' }} onClick={e => {
            props.onExpand(props.record, e);
        }}><Icon type="plus" /></a>
    }
}
```

Then inside of your table put:

```
<Table
    expandIcon={(props) => this.customExpandIcon(props)}
    ...
/>
```

This will allow you to use any combination of icons from antd in place of the expand/minimize buttons on the antd table.

Hope this 'll help you .