# Make a card component as drawer Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need a small help.

I am using Ant Design drawer, I want a particular card component as slides from the edge of the screen. I have searched regarding this But didn't get any solution. Please check the Sandbox and in that the card which is in left should slide from left. Please help me out. An image is attached for better understanding purposes.

SandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-leaf-0jj6p?file=/index.js

Link for Image: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4897738/d3c8150967f9b7ee17c8881562727b95

Thank you.

Comment: please can you clarify more ? because link has a already drawer .

Comment: like that particular card should be a drawer. Got it?

Comment: @vyas-arpit did you understand what is the problem here?

Comment: not perfectly. can your share some image of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: One minute. I will share image.

Comment: yeah please . Thank You :)

Comment: It is not uploading, So I am sharing the link for the image. Please check it once [link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4897738/d3c8150967f9b7ee17c8881562727b95)

Comment: okay i'll get back to you soon !

Comment: Thank You. Did you understand the problem?

Comment: yes perfectly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do with custom css like this .

in your react code do like this .

```
 <Drawer
      className="drawer-height"
        placement="left"
        width={250}
        closable={false}
        onClose={onClose}
        visible={visible}
      >
```

and add this in your css file .

```
.drawer-height {
  height  : 200px;
}
```

Hope this'll help !

Comment: yes. It will help me. Thank you. But I have one doubt, can't we make that card to move only?

Comment: move only mean ?

Comment: Like that card should slide from screen to right and vise versa?

Comment: No from left only. but the card itself slide. Can't we do like that?

Comment: we can do that but , we have to do with custom css and antd didn't give more  customization .

Comment: if you want more customization than from next time try to use material ui instead of ant d. it gives lot of customization with lightweight bundle size .

Comment: @Rich this ans doesn't satisfy your que ?

Comment: I was a bit busy. Now I have upvoted your answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If possible please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326450/set-value-to-state-react-js) once. I am struggling from past few hours. Thank you.