# Set value to state React js

Tags: reactjs, state, antd, setstate

I need a bit of help.

I am new to react, so I have stuck here. I have shared a `sandbox` box link. That Contains a Table. as below

| Toy | Color Available | Cost Available |

Now everything works perfectly. But I want to save the data of the table as below

The `detail` state should contain a list of row values of the table and the `columnsValues` should contain the checkbox value of `Color Available` and `Cost Available`

Example:
`this.state.detail` like

```
detail: [
  {
      toy   : ...
      color : ...
      cost  : ...
  }
  {
      toy   : ...
      color : ...
      cost  : ...
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
]
```

`this.state.columnsValues` like

```
columnsValues: {
  color : boolean
  cost  : boolean
}
```

Any experts please help me out. I am struggling from past few hours.

Thank you.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-microservice-qd3ku?file=/index.js

Comment: looks like you are already saving what you need in `this.state.detail` as `this.state.dataSource`?

Comment: Sorry for asking silly questions. But `dataSource` don't have the value I entered in table row.

Comment: you haven't got any initial state, why are you not setting that?

Comment: I am talking about the values which we enter in the textbox of rows. Where are we getting that from the initial state?

Comment: @Rich i am very close to your solution .

Comment: i'll share with you in sometime ;)

Comment: OK. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just paste this code it is working .

check your console you'll get your desired output .

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table, Checkbox, Input } from "antd";
import { PlusCircleOutlined, MinusCircleOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const { Column } = Table;

class ToyTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: [
        {
          key: 0,
          toy: "asdf",
          color: "black",
          cost: "23"
        }
      ],
      count: 0,
      colorSwitch: false,
      costSwitch: false,
      columnsValues: {
        color: true,
        cost: true
      },
      detail: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const count = this.state.dataSource.length;
    this.setState({
      count
    })
  }

  handleAdd = () => {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;
    let count = dataSource.length;
    const newData = {
      key: count,
      toy: "",
      color: "",
      cost: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      dataSource: [...dataSource, newData],
      count
    });
  };
  handleDelete = key => {
    const dataSource = [...this.state.dataSource];
    this.setState({ dataSource: dataSource.filter(item => item.key !== key) });
  };
  onChangecolor = (e, record) => {
    let dataSource = this.state.dataSource;
    let key = record.key;
    dataSource[key].color = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      dataSource
    });
  };
  onChangeCost = (e, record) => {
    let dataSource = this.state.dataSource;
    let key = record.key;
    dataSource[key].cost = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      dataSource
    });
  };
  onChangeToy = (e, record) => {
    console.log("I am inside handleInputChange", e.target.value, record);
    let dataSource = this.state.dataSource;
    let key = record.key;
    dataSource[key].toy = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      dataSource
    });
  };

  checkColor = e => {
    this.setState({ colorSwitch: e.target.checked });
  };

  checkCost = e => {
    this.setState({ costSwitch: e.target.checked });
  };
  render() {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;
    console.log(dataSource);

    return (
      <Table bordered pagination={false} dataSource={dataSource}>
        <Column
          title="Toy"
          align="center"
          key="toy"
          dataIndex="toy"
          render={(text, record) => (
            <Input
              component="input"
              className="ant-input"
              type="text"
              value={record.toy}
              onChange={e => this.onChangeToy(e, record)}
            />
          )}
        />

        <Column
          title={() => (
            <div className="row">
              Color Available
              <div className="col-md-5">
                <Checkbox size="small" onChange={this.checkColor} />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          align="center"
          dataIndex="color"
          render={(text, record) => (
            <Input
              disabled={!this.state.colorSwitch}
              value={record.color}
              onChange={e => this.onChangecolor(e, record)}
              component="input"
              className="ant-input"
              type="text"
            />
          )}
        />

        <Column
          title={() => (
            <div className="row">
              Cost Available
              <div className="col-md-5">
                <Checkbox size="small" onChange={this.checkCost} />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          align="center"
          dataIndex="color"
          render={(text, record) => (
            <Input
              disabled={!this.state.costSwitch}
              value={record.cost}
              onChange={e => this.onChangeCost(e, record)}
              component="input"
              className="ant-input"
              type="text"
            />
          )}
        />

        <Column
          render={(text, record) =>
            this.state.count !== 0 && record.key + 1 !== this.state.count ? (
              <MinusCircleOutlined
                onClick={() => this.handleDelete(record.key)}
              />
            ) : (
              <PlusCircleOutlined onClick={this.handleAdd} />
            )
          }
        />
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ToyTable />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Happy to have helped :). I have to because i have told you i'll get back to you in 2 hours 

Comment: Anyways thanks for the concern. But your code will give an error when we remove a row(minus icon at right) and then add another one and try to change that row's value. Right now I am checking the same. If possible please check that once. Thank you. :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply . But i was little busy today. So , can't help you today.

Comment: It's ok. No problem. If possible please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345611/expand-a-row-by-click-of-table-on-a-certain-condition-ant-design-table-react-js) once. It looks simple, But I didn't found any solution yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exact answer, but just as a general direction - you need something in the `state` to capture the values of the currently edited row contents, that you can then add to the final list. This is assuming once committed, you don't want to modify the final list.

Firstly, have an initial state that stores the values in the current row being edited

```
this.state = {
  currentData: {
    toy: '',
    color: '', 
    ..other props in the row
  }
  ...other state variables like dataSource etc
}
```

Secondly, when the value in an input box is changed, you have to update the corresponding property in the `currentData` state variable. I see that you already have a `handleInputChange` function

For eg, for the input box corresponding to `toy`, you'd do

```
 <input onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, 'toy')} ...other props />
```

and in the function itself, you'd update the currentData state variable, something like:

```
handleInputChange = (e, property) => {
  const data = this.state.currentData 
  data[property] = e.target.value
  this.setState({ currentData: data })
}
```

Finally, when you press add, in your `handleAddFunction`, you want to do two things:

1) use the `currentData` in state, that's been saving your current values and push them into the `dataSource` or `details` array

2) restore the `currentData` to the blank state, ready to track updates for the next row.

```
  handleAdd = () => {
    const { count, dataSource } = this.state;
    const newData = {
      key: count,
      ...this.state.newData,
    };
    this.setState({
      dataSource: [...dataSource, newData],
      count: count + 1, 
      currentData: {
        toy: '', 
        // other default values
      }
    });
  };
```